# Install/importing R packages into python with rpy2, imports/ignores the packet in question

Tags: python, r, rpy2, kolmogorov-smirnov

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. I want to use the [discrete Kolmogorov-Smirov Goodness-of-fit test](https://rdrr.io/cran/dgof/man/ks.test.html), which is currently only available in R. Further, [R has the normal KS test as well](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ks.test.html) -- I do not want to use this test.
2. I am a python user, so need to port the discrete KS test to python, to do this [I am trying to use](https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/robjects_rpackages.html) `rpy2`.

**The problem I am facing**, as detailed in more statistical detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54083887/discrete-kolmogorov-smirnov-testing-getting-wrong-value-when-using-rpy2-compare?noredirect=1#comment95038606_54083887), is that `rpy2` seems to replace the imported discrete test with the standard version. I know this because it does not produce the right answer when tested.

**Attempts so far**

```
import rpy2.robjects.packages as r
utils = r.importr("utils")
package_name = "dgof"
utils.install_packages(package_name)
```

results in

```
/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:146: RRuntimeWarning: 

  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:146: RRuntimeWarning: 
  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:146: RRuntimeWarning: The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpTBas6a/downloaded_packages’
  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:146: RRuntimeWarning: Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'

  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:146: RRuntimeWarning: Making 'packages.html' ...
  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:146: RRuntimeWarning:  done

  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
rpy2.rinterface.NULL
```

Ok, so far so good, that should have installed it. So lets import it:

```
# Import Discrete goodness-of-fit package which includes KS and CVM tests.
dgof = rpackages.importr('dgof')
```

Has it really imported it? Lets see:

```
env = r.wherefrom('dgof')
```

returns

```
/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:146: RRuntimeWarning: Error: object 'dgof' not found

  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:146: RRuntimeWarning: In addition: 
  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:146: RRuntimeWarning: Warning message:

  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:146: RRuntimeWarning: In (function (x, y, ..., alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"),  :
  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:146: RRuntimeWarning: 

  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:146: RRuntimeWarning:  cannot compute correct p-values with ties

  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)

  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
```

Ok that's weird, but maybe it works anyway, lets see ([this is exactly the same example as used on the R side](https://rdrr.io/cran/dgof/man/ks.test.html) and should return `D = 0.66667, p-value = 0.07407`) :

```
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,1,1])
b = np.arange(1,3)
dgof.ks_test(a,b)
```

returns

```
D = 0.5, p-value = 0.925086
```

If this doesn't mean anything to you that's fine, what you need to know is that it is wrong. It seems to be wrong because, somehow, the standard `ks_test` is being loaded in place of the discrete one (the one we talk about in item 2 in the above list). Lets verify, by loading the standard library and the KS test:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
base     = importr('base')
stats    = importr('stats')
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,1,1])
b = np.arange(1,3)
stats.ks_test(a,b)
```

returns

```
D = 0.5, p-value = 0.925086
```

So that's cool -- does anyone know why this may be happening?

**NOTE:** [this question is related to my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54083887/discrete-kolmogorov-smirnov-testing-getting-wrong-value-when-using-rpy2-compare?noredirect=1#comment95038606_54083887), but with lots more detail on the python side of things.

Answer (score 0):

> Has it really imported it? Lets see:
>
> ```
> env = r.wherefrom('dgof')
> ```
>
> returns
>
> ```
> /home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:146: RRuntimeWarning: Error: object 'dgof' not found
> ```

The `RRuntimeWarning` comes from R itself, and is what one would expect. There is no object `dgof` because R package namespaces are not objects.

What you want is likely `wherefrom('ks.test')` (see
https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/robjects_rpackages.html#finding-where-an-r-symbol-is-coming-from).

Many things can be happening here between, depending on what the package 'dgof' is doing (if you are coming from Python, R can let package developers do really strange things).

Did you try relying on R's dispatch and function overloading mechanisms ? After loading the R package `dgof`, call `ks.test` without specifying a namespace.

```
dgof = rpackages.importr('dgof')
import rpy2.robjects
# "generic" function ks.test
ks_test = rpy2.robjects.r('ks.test')
# Use it
ks_test(a, b)
```

Comment: Hi! I gave this a shot but it still does not work I am afraid.

Comment: Well, since this using R's own dispatch for `ks.test`, either the variables your are passing through rpy2 differ, or there is something else with the pure R version you are reporting to be working (I don't have `dgof` to try at the moment). To assess the former, try the following to see how your  Python vectors get converted: `robjects.globalenv['a']` then `robjects.r('print(a)')`